# Cannot mount iOmega 1TB HDD

Tags: mount, hard-drive

HDD works flawlessly on my Windows 7. But when I connect it to this machine (Ubuntu 12.04) I get this error message;

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: only root can mount /dev/sdc1 on /media/Iomega_HDD
```

Can someone please help?

Here's the fdisk -l output w/ HDD connected;

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0005d463

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   308914175   154456064   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       308916222   312580095     1831937    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       308916224   312580095     1831936   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Note: sector size is 4096 (not 512)

Disk /dev/sdc: 999.5 GB, 999460397056 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15188 cylinders, total 244008886 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5dd861ea

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1             256   244187647   976749568    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: "only root can mount" what do you think this means? (the answer: put sudo in front of the mount command or change the owner of the mount point  ;-) ) fdisk output is unneeded. You need to do an `ls -l /media/`.

Comment: Sorry but I am fairly new to this OS. The output I got from that command is too long to paste here, but I could not tell where to go from there. Any chance of more in depth help?

Comment: Use http://paste.ubuntu.com/ if the output is too long, then add the link to your question. (Strange by itself, `ls -l /media` should output not so many lines...)

Comment: @southern_bman it should not be that long?! (it should list all mounted items in /media.I hardly see more than a few lines when ever it is listed ;)

Comment: @southern_bman is this sufficient as an answer? If not PM me!

Comment: When asking for help with an error from a command, you need to specify *what* command you were trying to run.

Comment: I get the "only root can mount" dialogue when I connect the HDD, before I attempt to use any commands.

Comment: Also, @Rinzwind, I cannot find any way to PM you as your profile has no contact info.

Answer (score 1):

> mount: only root can mount /dev/sdc1 on /media/Iomega_HDD

Linux, in contrary to Windows, uses a permissions method where users on the system can do some things and where 1 user (our of the box;it can be more) can elevate permissions to do administrator things. Your mount command is probably correct but needs `sudo` in from of it. So the command will start like this:

```
sudo mount ...
```

After you supply the admin password it should mount but it will still be owned by root so -any- action on the disc that is changing the disc (delete/write etc) will require your admin password.

For a normal user to mount Iomega_HDD you need to change the ownership of that directory from root to that user.  You can do that with the following command:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/Iomega_HDD
```

($USER is automatically translated to the user name you use to do this). This is a permanent solution: every next time you mount it you can do that with the user.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. Could you tell me the exact command I should use?